# C# .NET WPF - DataTable (SQLite) as DataGrid source with Grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatable, datagrid

I'm new into WPF and can't get it to display my data from SQLite DB in grouped form. Can anyone help?

My latest version throws me an error after compilation: `object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

I don't insist on using the datatable as a source, I just need to display a data from SQL table in a grouped way. The best option would be to combine two queries so the group details would come from query 1 and data rows would come from query two. As in SQL tables are connected on specific column.

C# code below.

```
// Fired on Window_Loaded event
public void FillDataGridFromSQL()
{
        SQLiteConnection oSQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=rem_test_database.db");
        SQLiteCommand oCommand = oSQLiteConnection.CreateCommand();
        oCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM first_table";
        m_oDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(oCommand.CommandText, oSQLiteConnection);
        SQLiteCommandBuilder oCommandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(m_oDataAdapter);

        m_oDataSet = new DataSet();
        m_oDataAdapter.Fill(m_oDataSet);
        m_oDataTable = m_oDataSet.Tables[0];

        CollectionView collectionView = new CollectionView(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(m_oDataTable.DefaultView));
        // Line below produce exception!
        collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("id_nieruchomosci"));
        LeftDataGrid.ItemsSource = collectionView;
}
```

and XAML markup:

```
<!-- DataGrid -->
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Name="LeftDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <!-- Grouping style-->
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding id_nieruchomosci}" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding id_nieruchomosci, StringFormat=Count: {0}}" Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <!-- Columns Definitions -->
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="id_nieruchomosci" Binding="{Binding id_nieruchomosci}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="frakcja" Binding="{Binding frakcja}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="fld_results">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Content="X" Click="Button_Click"/>
                            <Button Content="E" Click="Button_Click"/>
                            <Button Content="M" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Which line produces the exception?

Comment: C# `collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new propertyGroupDescription("id_nieruchomosci"));` produces an exception. //Marked in code

Comment: MSDN ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.groupdescriptions?view=netframework-4.8 ) states that .GroupDescriptions 'is always null because the CollectionView class does not support grouping over its underlying collection. The derived classes ListCollectionView and BindingListCollectionView do support grouping.' . Might be worth to try ListCollectionView instead of CollectionView, but this is just my blind guess

Comment: Still can't get it work. I cant just feed ListCollectionView with DataTable object as I did with CollectionView (or I don't know how to feed it with this data).

Comment: Use a collectionviewsource instead. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1da1521f-fd8a-42c7-a47c-fb58b13974db/how-to-group-datagrid-which-itemssource-is-dataview-from-datatabaleasdataview-?forum=wpf Which uses dt.AsDataView on the datatable to get a dataview which is then used as the source of a collectionviewsource.

Comment: Great, works perfectly - thanks. Here comes another question. My data are arranged in two relative tables like Buildings and Families in these buildings. Every building has it's address (in multiple collumns) and unique ID. Then each Family is assigned to Building it lives in by the BuildingID. What will be the best way to show data arranged like that in grouped DataGrid. So the group header contains House_Street, House_number, Count(families) ? And the rows display details abou each family?